# How to configurate netbeans8 with symfony3?

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans-8

I have installed symfony3.2.4 ,netbeans8.2 
[image]

Now I have downloded netbeans8, I have tried to configure symfony on netbeans 8

[image]

[image]

I don’t know what I should select as file (full path of symphony installer)!!

In the example that I followed from http://wiki.netbeans.org/NB68symfony , I don’t have data\bin\symfony due to different of version
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony installer location would be the location where you download Symfony using:

```
php -r "readfile('https://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony
```

on Windows [as per the instructions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html). A good location for this would be `C:\bin` where you should also [install Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows).

**Please note:** That tutorial you show is out of date. I suggest you instead follow [the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) and go through that instead. Following an old tutorial is not going to help you at all.